# How to Fix my JavaScript code to succeed in displaying "ON" or "OFF" texts with each click on the checkbox Button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, checkbox

The idea for me is to add on and off functionality in PHP and Ajax later. But for the moment, I am facing an `on` and `off` text display error when activating Visa and Mastercard cards whose HTML code is as follows:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 mb-lg-0 mb-3">
                <div class="card p-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <div class="img-box"><img src="cardimg/visa.png" alt=""></div>
                            <div class="number"><label class="fw-bold" for="">**** **** **** 1060</label></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <form method="post" class="toggleForm">
                                <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1" name='machine_state'>
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" id="statusText1" for="customSwitch1"></label>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
 
                    <div class="row">
                            <small class="col-9">
                                <span class="fw-bold">Expiry date:</span>
                            </small>
                            <small class="col-3">
                                <span>10/16</span>
                            </small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 mb-lg-0 mb-3">
                <div class="card p-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <div class="img-box"><img src="cardimg/mastercard.png" alt=""></div>
                            <div class="number"><label class="fw-bold" for="">**** **** **** 1060</label></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <form method="post" class="toggleForm">
                                <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch2" name='machine_state'>
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" id="statusText2" for="customSwitch2"></label>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
 
                    <div class="row">
                            <small class="col-9">
                                <span class="fw-bold">Expiry date:</span>
                            </small>
                            <small class="col-3">
                                <span>10/16</span>
                            </small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And a 1st JS code of **ids** `customSwitch1` and `statusText1`:

```
function putStatus() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://api.srv3r.com/toggle/",
        data: {toggle_select: true},
        success: function (result) {
            if (result == 1) {
                $('#customSwitch1').prop('checked', true);
                statusText1(1);
            } else {
                $('#customSwitch1').prop('checked', false);
                statusText1(0);
            }
        }
    });
}
 
function statusText1(status_val) {
    if (status_val == 1) {
        var status_str = "On";
    } else {
        var status_str = "Off";
    }
    document.getElementById("statusText1").innerText = status_str;
}
 
function onToggle() {
    $('#toggleForm :checkbox').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            //alert('checked');
            updateStatus(1);
            statusText1(1);
        } else {
            //alert('NOT checked');
            updateStatus(0);
            statusText1(0);
        }
    });
}
 
function updateStatus(status_val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://api.srv3r.com/toggle/",
        data: {toggle_update: true, status: status_val},
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
 
$(document).ready(function () {
    putStatus();//Set button to current status
    onToggle();//Update when toggled
    statusText1();//Last updated text
});
```

And the second JavaScript code of **ids** `customSwitch2` and `statusText2`:

```
function putStatus() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://api.srv3r.com/toggle/",
        data: {toggle_select: true},
        success: function (result) {
            if (result == 1) {
                $('#customSwitch2').prop('checked', true);
                statusText2(1);
            } else {
                $('#customSwitch2').prop('checked', false);
                statusText2(0);
            }
        }
    });
}
 
function statusText2(status_val) {
    if (status_val == 1) {
        var status_str = "On";
    } else {
        var status_str = "Off";
    }
    document.getElementById("statusText2").innerText = status_str;
}
 
function onToggle() {
    $('#toggleForm :checkbox').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            //alert('checked');
            updateStatus(1);
            statusText2(1);
        } else {
            //alert('NOT checked');
            updateStatus(0);
            statusText2(0);
        }
    });
}
 
function updateStatus(status_val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://api.srv3r.com/toggle/",
        data: {toggle_update: true, status: status_val},
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
 
$(document).ready(function () {
    putStatus();//Set button to current status
    onToggle();//Update when toggled
    statusText2();//Last updated text
});
```

The problem is that when I click on the `Checkbox` button, at the HTML page level, I should in principle have a `toggle` effect that changes from `on` to `off` with each click.

But the problem is that the `statusText1` and `statusText2` representing the `on` and `off` texts remain static instead of changing each time the checkbox button is clicked.

So help me to fix my JavaScript code above so that it successfully changes text from `on` to `off` every time I click.

***Also is there a way to synchronize the use of the Enable and Disable Checkbox Button of the different Ids instead of doing them separately in two different codes which are almost identical ???***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've have fixed the "On" and "Off" issue and ***"synchronize the use of the Enable and Disable Checkbox Button"***. Kindly try this code

```js
function putStatus(target) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://api.srv3r.com/toggle/",
        data: {toggle_select: true},
        success: function (result) {
            if (result == 1) {
                $(target).prop('checked', true);
            } else {
                $(target).prop('checked', false);
            }
        }
    });
}
 
function updateStatus(status_val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://api.srv3r.com/toggle/",
        data: {toggle_update: true, status: status_val},
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
 
$(document).ready(function () {
    // putStatus('#customSwitch1');
    // putStatus('#customSwitch2');

    $('.statuses').change(function () {
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            updateStatus(1);
            $(this).next().text('On');
        }else{
            updateStatus(0);
            $(this).next().text('Off');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-lg-3 mb-lg-0 mb-3">
    <div class="card p-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="img-box"><img src="cardimg/visa.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="number"><label class="fw-bold" for="">**** **** **** 1060</label></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <form method="post" class="toggleForm">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input statuses" id="customSwitch1" name="machine_state">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Off</label>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <small class="col-9">
                <span class="fw-bold">Expiry date:</span>
            </small>
            <small class="col-3">
                <span>10/16</span>
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 mb-lg-0 mb-3">
    <div class="card p-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="img-box"><img src="cardimg/mastercard.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="number"><label class="fw-bold" for="">**** **** **** 1060</label></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <form method="post" class="toggleForm">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input statuses" id="customSwitch2" name="machine_state">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch2">Off</label>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <small class="col-9">
                <span class="fw-bold">Expiry date:</span>
            </small>
            <small class="col-3">
                <span>10/16</span>
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great thanks. It works well.

Comment: Happy to help. Kindly consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: it's done. Thanks.